# Can I hold data in memory on HTTPGET?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am calling data from a server via an api call on a grid page change . When calling this method I dynamically get the table schema for all columns and do other work with it on the angular side.

The issue is I only need to get this table data once.

How can I hold the data in memory so that if the user changes a page on the client side I don't have to hit the database again just to get schema data?

```
 [Route("api/MyRoute/GetData/{Skip}/{Take}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetData(string Skip, string Take)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Result == null)
                {
                    Result = DynamicSqlQuery(Convert.ToInt32(Skip), Convert.ToInt32(Take));
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wan't is save the data in the angular side, you can in the service you make the http call for example

```
dataStructure = [];

getDataStructure() {

   if (this.dataStructure) {
      return this.dataStructure;
   }else{

  return this.http.get<any>(
           this.url + 'values',
                { headers: headers }
              ).pipe( 
                tap( data => this.cachedData = data )
              );

   }                        
}
```

tap will not subscribe, you subscribe as normal in your component, when data arrives, tap saves a copy in memory, so next call returns that copy.

Please see an example in SB ( option 12 ): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu

you can see in the log that first call is fetched from server, then from cache.